# Multiplexing the Future<> in Java

Tags: java

I find myself about to write a class that `implements Future<T>` and stores, inside of itself, a `Collection<Future<T>>`, acting as an aggregate future for all of its contents.

I wonder: has anyone already done this in some open source library? A bit of googling didn't yield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "aggregate future."  Perhaps Guava's [`Futures.allAsList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList%28java.lang.Iterable%29)?